# Pinescript giving unexpected alerts

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading, pyalgotrade

i am new  to this automated trading, but recently i developed a system using supertrend and breakouts. but i am facing trouble in setting alerts, 90% time they are working fine but sometimes i am getting alerts without even signal is generated.

problems faced till now:

1. TP alert before it actually gets trigger, 1 or 2 candle before the signal is generated.
2. long signal is generated, quantity is bought but after 2 candle again got the message of long without any relevant signal generated on trading view, causing binance to buy double the quantity.

////////////////////script////////////////////

```
`//@version=5
strategy("MATIC algo supertrend", overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100, process_orders_on_close=true)
import PineCoders/VisibleChart/4

atrPeriod = input(30, "ATR Length")
factor = input.float(3.02, "Factor", step = 0.01)

[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(factor, atrPeriod)

bodyMiddle = plot((open + close) / 2, display=display.none)
upTrend = plot(direction < 0 ? supertrend : na, "Up Trend", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
downTrend = plot(direction < 0? na : supertrend, "Down Trend", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr)

fill(bodyMiddle, upTrend, color.new(color.green, 90), fillgaps=false)
fill(bodyMiddle, downTrend, color.new(color.red, 90), fillgaps=false)

//@version=5

length = input.int(12, 'Swing Detection Lookback')
mult = input.float(0., 'Slope', minval = 0, step = .1)
calcMethod = input.string('Atr', 'Slope Calculation Method', options = ['Atr','Stdev','Linreg'])
backpaint = input(false, tooltip = 'Backpainting offset displayed elements in the past. Disable backpainting to see real time information returned by the indicator.')

//Style
upCss = input.color(color.teal, 'Up Trendline Color', group = 'Style')
dnCss = input.color(color.red, 'Down Trendline Color', group = 'Style')
showExt = input(true, 'Show Extended Lines')

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Calculations
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var upper = 0.
var lower = 0.
var slope_ph = 0.
var slope_pl = 0.

var offset = backpaint ? length : 0

n = bar_index
src = close

ph = ta.pivothigh(length, length)
pl = ta.pivotlow(length, length)

//Slope Calculation Method
slope = switch calcMethod
    'Atr'    => ta.atr(length) / length * mult
    'Stdev'  => ta.stdev(src,length) / length * mult
    'Linreg' => math.abs(ta.sma(src * n, length) - ta.sma(src, length) * ta.sma(n, length)) / ta.variance(n, length) / 2 * mult

//Get slopes and calculate trendlines
slope_ph := ph ? slope : slope_ph
slope_pl := pl ? slope : slope_pl

upper := ph ? ph : upper - slope_ph
lower := pl ? pl : lower + slope_pl

var upos = 0
var dnos = 0
upos := ph ? 0 : close > upper - slope_ph * length ? 1 : upos
dnos := pl ? 0 : close < lower + slope_pl * length ? 1 : dnos

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Extended Lines
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
var uptl  = line.new(na,na,na,na, color = upCss, style = line.style_dashed, extend = extend.right)
var dntl  = line.new(na,na,na,na, color = dnCss, style = line.style_dashed, extend = extend.right)

if ph and showExt
    uptl.set_xy1(n-offset, backpaint ? ph : upper - slope_ph * length)
    uptl.set_xy2(n-offset+1, backpaint ? ph - slope : upper - slope_ph * (length+1))

if pl and showExt
    dntl.set_xy1(n-offset, backpaint ? pl : lower + slope_pl * length)
    dntl.set_xy2(n-offset+1, backpaint ? pl + slope : lower + slope_pl * (length+1))

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
//Plots
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------{
plot(backpaint ? upper : upper - slope_ph * length, 'Upper', color = ph ? na : upCss, offset = -offset)
plot(backpaint ? lower : lower + slope_pl * length, 'Lower', color = pl ? na : dnCss, offset = -offset)

//Breakouts
plotshape(upos > upos[1] ? low : na, "Upper Break"
  , shape.labelup
  , location.absolute
  , upCss
  , text = "B"
  , textcolor = color.white
  , size = size.tiny)

plotshape(dnos > dnos[1] ? high : na, "Lower Break"
  , shape.labeldown
  , location.absolute
  , dnCss
  , text = "B"
  , textcolor = color.white
  , size = size.tiny)
 
TP = 0.02
SOS = 0.005
SL = 0.15
 
///longs//
if ta.change(direction) < 0 
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long) 
    alert("close MATICUSDT a=USDM \nbuy MATICUSDT q=500% a=USDM")

if ((strategy.position_size > 0) and close > strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + TP))
    strategy.exit(id = "TP" , stop = low)
    alert("close MATICUSDT a=USDMM")

if ta.change((direction) < 0 and upos > upos[1] and strategy.position_size == 0)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
    alert("buy MATICUSDT q=500% a=USDM")
 

//shorts//
if ta.change(direction) > 0
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
    alert("close MATICUSDT a=USDM \nsell MATICUSDT q=500% a=USDM")

if ((strategy.position_size < 0) and close < strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - TP))
    strategy.exit(id = "TP" ,stop = high)
    alert("close MATICUSDT a=USDMM")
 
if ta.change((direction) > 0 and dnos > dnos[1] and strategy.position_size == 0)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
    alert("sell MATICUSDT q=500% a=USDM")`

help pls
thank youuu


i just want regular alerts without any repainting or false signals
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your *strategy.exit* has *stop*, but no **limit**
   You must use *limit* for TP
2. Your code has **six** *strategy.entry*. That's why you have multiple entries.
   It should have one *strategy.entry* for long, and one *strategy.entry* for short.
   Now it has two long entries, and two short entries.

Comment: i posted an image please refer that, i am newbie , if u know how to simplify this thing ill be thankful.

Comment: this error occurs because you [backtest on non-standard graphics](https://www.tradingview.com/script/q9laJNG9-Backtesting-on-Non-Standard-Charts-Caution-PineCoders-FAQ/)